# Login account credentials not working

Tags: support, login

There seems to be a mix up with my login account credentials. Whenever I go to a site that wants me to use Stack Exchange to login, that site will not accept my email as a valid login.

I use the one that is represented in my account profile page, but "Get Code Done" for example, does not recognize the email as a Stack Exchange email.

Answer (score 1):

You're not logging in with a Stack Exchange credential. Click the "Google" button and you should be all set.